# Correct way to write nested if statements?

Tags: javascript, nested-if

`numberHands` will be equal to `1,2, or 3`. It will never make it this far in the program if not. So I see no reason for else statements.

But, is this the correct syntax for writing nested if statements in JavaScript? I feel like the closing brackets are incorrect, but I'm new to js. How would you write this?

```
function recap() {
    if (numberHands > 0) {
        wonOrLost(h1.cards, h1);
    }
        if (numberHands > 1) {
            wonOrLost(h2.cards, h2);
        }
            if (numberHands > 2) {
                wonOrLost(h3.cards, h3);
            }
    playAgainOption();
}
```

Comment: In your case, if numberHands is 3, all three statements will be executed, is this intentional?

Comment: This might be a better case for a switch statement.

Comment: Those are not "nested" `if` statements. It's a sequence of three separate `if` statements.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes. if numberHands = 3 then all 3 must execute.. if = 1 then just the 1st, if 2 then the first 2 but not 3rd

Comment: What does the wonOrLost code look like? A nice thing would be to factor in the numberOfHands in that function instead.

Comment: your if statements are not nested... use case statement like mentioned by ohiodoug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the closing brackets are in the wrong place. What you are looking for is

```
function recap() {
    if (numberHands > 0) {
        wonOrLost(h1.cards, h1);
        if (numberHands > 1) {
            wonOrLost(h2.cards, h2);
            if (numberHands > 2) {
                wonOrLost(h3.cards, h3);
            }
        }
    }
    playAgainOption();
}
```

**NOTE**

This is functionally identical to what you currently have.

Comment: Indeed, but OP was asking about nested statements. I am showing what the nested statement looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try...

```
function recap() {
    switch(numberHands) {
        case 3:
            wonOrLost(h3.cards, h3);
        case 2:
            wonOrLost(h2.cards, h2);
        case 1:
            wonOrLost(h1.cards, h1);
    }
    playAgainOption();
}
```

It looks like the order these functions execute doesn't matter as long as they all get called. To me, this solutions feels more elegant.

Good luck!

Comment: You need to look up how a switch/case statement works. This solution is doing EXACTLY what you need it to. After one of the cases evaluates to true, every statement after it will execute unless there is a break. Because there is no break in this statement, after 3 evaluates to true, every case will execute after it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it isn't nested, but it will still work the same way. That's because

- If `numberHands > 1` then it's by definition `> 0` as well.
- If `numberHands > 2` then it's by definition `> 1` and `> 0` as well.

The proper syntax of a nested if statements would be

```
if (condition) {
    doSomething();
    if (anotherCondition) {
        doSomethingElse();
        if (aThirdCondition) {
            doSomethingDifferent();
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you have several, separate if statements, which are not related to one another, aside for the fact that if one is true, all others behind it are true as well.

---

<s>If you did not intend for all of them to run if `numberHands` is equal to 3 , then a `switch/case` structure is more suitable, and more readable:</s> OP clarified that he did intend for all of them to run.

```
switch (numberHands) {
    case 1:
        wonOrLost(h1.cards, h1);
        break;
    case 2:
        wonOrLost(h2.cards, h2);
        break;
    case 3:
        wonOrLost(h3.cards, h3);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a nested `if` statement, but it's certainly an alternative if you plan on adding more conditions.

```
var list = [h1,h2,h3];
for (var i = 0; i < numberHands; i++) {
    wonOrLost(list[i].cards, list[i]);
}
```

Comment: This answer, while no answer to the original question, is by far the best because it teaches proper modelling.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If numberHands = 1, only list[0] will get called.

Comment: @linstantnoodles For a new programmer (as the OP seems to be), this might just be confusing and (IMHO) it really doesn't answer the question as asked!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're not used to write with the markdown editor, but that's incorrectly indented.

```
function recap() {
    if (numberHands > 0) { // 1 or more
        wonOrLost(h1.cards, h1);
        if (numberHands > 1) {
            wonOrLost(h2.cards, h2); // 2 or more
        }
        if (numberHands > 2) {
            wonOrLost(h3.cards, h3); // 3 or more
        }
    }
    playAgainOption();
}
```